# Firefox not recognizing a defined object (Firefox Extension development)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox extension (I'm a newbie to this, so please go easy), and I seem to be stuck with a very annoying problem that is hindering me from making any progress.

I have three .js files: `main.js`, `hello.js`, `awesome.js` and one .xul file, `awesomeOverlay.xul`. The `main.js` goes something like this:

```js
//main.js

if(typeof(MyExtension) === "undefined") {
    var MyExtension = {};
}

MyExtension.Main = {
    browser : null,

    init : function() {
        if("gBrowser" in window) {
            MyExtension.Main.browser = window.gBrowser;
            MyExtension.Main.browser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", MyExtension.Main.onPageLoad, true);
            window.content.console.log("Yay, recognized the browser!");
    },

    onPageLoad : function(e) {
        var doc = e.originalTarget;
        var regex = /stackoverflow\.com/;
        if(regex.test(doc.location.href)) {
            window.content.console.log("Visiting stackoverflow!");
            alert("Loaded stackoverflow!");
        }

        e.originalTarget.defaultView.addEventListener("unload", function(e){MyExtension.Main.onPageUnload(e), true);
    },

    onPageUnload : function(e) {
        var regex = /stackoverflow\.com/;
        var doc = e.originalTarget;
        if(regex.test(doc.location.href)) {
            alert("Found a solution to your problem, huh? Great!");
        }
    }
};
```

In my other two .js files, I have objects like `MyExtension.Hello = {...}` and `MyExtension.Awesome = {...}`. The issue is, when I load stackoverflow.com, I do not get any alerts or logs in the console. I loaded up Scratchpad, changed the Environment context to "Browser", and verified if the objects I defined existed by `alert(typeof(MyExtension))`, and it returns "object" as expected. When I tried `alert(typeof(MyExtension.Main))`, I got "undefined". In fact, I get "undefined" for `alert(typeof(MyExtension.Main.*))`.

When I tried checking the typeof of objects in the other two files (hello.js and awesome.js), they are correctly recognized (i.e., "function", "object" etc.). It seems like the main.js file is being ignored for some reason. This is how my .xul file is defined:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://myextension/skin/myextension.css" type="text/css"?>
<overlay id="AwesomeOverlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://myextension/content/jquery.min.js" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://myextension/content/main.js" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://myextension/content/hello.js" />
   <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://myextension/content/awesome.js" />
   <statusbar id="status-bar">
       <statusbarpanel id="myextensionAwesomeStatusBar" context="myextensionSB" class="shown" persist="class">
           <hbox id="myextensionHbox" class="shown" persist="class">
               <image id="awesomeIcon" tooltiptext="Awesome Extension \m/" class="shown" persist="class" />
           </hbox>
       </statusbarpanel>
   </statusbar>
</overlay>
```

I've verified that the paths in the chrome.manifest are correct. This is driving me nuts, please help!

Comment: Are you exporting your objects?

Comment: @user1269964: No, I don't know how to do that. As I said, I'm a beginner to FF extension development. Should I be exporting them?

However, when trying out a few things, I declared the `MyExtension` object inline, inside a `<script>` tag, in the .xul file, and it works. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Since `MyExtension.Main` is defined in `main.js`, you might want to try

```
exports.MyExtension = MyExtension;
```

in `main.js`, somewhere after where `MyExtension.Main` is assigned, and

```
main = require("main");
```

in the file(s) from which you invoke `typeof(MyExtension.Main)` (since the property `Main` is defined in `main.js`) and access the object as `typeof(main.MyExtensions.Main)`

This is assuming all of your .js files are in the `lib` folder.  I'm not sure how (if) XUL affects this.  I've never messed with XUL; am more of a newbie than yourself with that particular technology.